# Specify Max Parquet Block Size in PySpark

Tags: csv, pyspark, parquet

I can sucessfully convert a CSV file into a Parquet file, but the Parquet file is broken into a ton of 2-3mb files. As an example a ~25gb CSV gets transformed into a Parquet file with over 700 files. My research shows it should be between 256mb and 1gb. How do I specify the size upfront?

I've seen that Impala does it via PARQUET_FILE_SIZE. I haven't been able to find anything for PySpark. Example code below:

```
df.write.mode("overwrite").parquet("s3n://%s:%s@%s/%s" % (ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, AWS_BUCKET_NAME, FOLDER_FOR_PARQUET_RESULTS))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df \
.repartition(100) \
.write \
.mode("overwrite") \
.parquet("s3n://%s:%s@%s/%s" % (ACCESS_KEY, SECRET_KEY, \
AWS_BUCKET_NAME, FOLDER_FOR_PARQUET_RESULTS))
```

Repartition will, well, repartition your dataframe into 100 partitions (approximately 256mb in size - uncompressed) this should create bigger parquet files.

Comment: Right, but my original file size will change so I'd rather specify upfront the file size vs having to estimate the number of partitions.